# Is Job 15:7 referring to wisdom from Proverbs 8:25 or to Adam?

Tags: referent-identification, job, proverbs

NET Bible

> Job 15:7 Were you the first man ever born? Were you brought forth
>   before the hills?
>
> Proverbs 8:25 before the mountains were settled in place, before the
>   hills, I was given birth,

Who does Eliphaz understand to be "the first man ever born"?

Comment: Proverbs 8 is Wisdom personified as a woman, not a man.

Comment: @RevelationLad I believe that is only a play on the grammatical gender of the word 'wisdom' (Heb. ḥokmâ/Gk. sophia) and not integral, as such, to the personification.

Comment: @SolaGratia https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7883/why-is-wisdom-personified-as-a-woman

Comment: @RevelationLad Interesting read. I tend not convict the wisdom literature of promotic archaic practices of worshiping goddesses, since I'm a Christian, but also because it's a highly subjective, and I believe, markdely eisegetical move. Especially given how wisdom is often most explicitly synonymized with other synonymous words, such as prudence, counsel, knowledge—that is, whith being a simple personification of God's good virtues/attributes. Or even sometimes with the 'spirit/Spirit' of God.

Comment: @SolaGratia I don't disagree with you. I think you are on solid ground. I see the issue as taking the verse in Proverbs "out of context" attempting to link it to Job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is parallelism here which we must take into account. With parallelism, it's not always clear whether equating the two parallel concepts is *intended by the author or not*, and is largely a subjective endeavor, however, I think this case is quite clear:

> **Job 15:7-8**
>
> Are you the **first man** that was born | or | were you **made before the hills?**
>
> Have thou heard *God's counsel*  | and |  shall you take away *wisdom* to yourself?

Since *Proverbs*, also Wisdom Literature, written after *Job* and based on the same idea of personifying God's wisdom, says the following:

> **Proverbs 8:12,25**
>
> I, *wisdom* ... ... The mountains with their huge bulk had not as yet been established: **before the hills I was brought forth:**

This seems to be quite an overt allusion to this *passage*. However, wisdom is not a "man born," but a personification of God's wisdom. **It seems to be the case, therefore, that *Job 15:7a* and *Job 15:7b* might not be equating "the first man" with being "made before the hills," as this is not a necessary link. It's more likely two successive examples of being of prime importance:** the first manever born; 'God thought it essential to make you, even before getting around to making the mountains' (accusing Job or pride, or mocking his futility).

Comment: I have heard it argued that the hills were not made until the flood.

Comment: @Ruminator That sounds like a rather baseless assumption to me...